# Response body of GET request is empty

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a simple GET request to my server. URL is right, it gives json using python function. But I can't get the same data in  javascript. Something is wrong with this function.

```
        async function get_status(){
            socket.send("Status!");
            URL = http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/status/';
            response = await fetch(URL, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                }
            })
            socket.send(response.json());
            console.log(response.json());
            if (response.ok) {
                current = document.getElementById("status");
                current.value= response.json()["status"];
             }
        };
```

Comment: If you copy the content of `URL` and paste it into a browser, does it produce the required result? further, please add the value of `URL` to the question.

Comment: @alfasin yes, i see the json

Comment: what's the exact value of `URL`? it can't be "myURL"!

Comment: It will give nothing by adding URL because nobody will have access to it

Comment: True (that we don't have access), but it will still be valuable!

Comment: Of course it's not myURL

Comment: Help me help you :)

Comment: I suspect that the `URL` you're using looks something like: `localhost:8080` while `fetch` requires the url to start with http/https

Comment: I added URL @alfasin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
const response = await fetch(URL);
if (response.ok) {
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    socket.send(json);
    current = document.getElementById("status");
    current.value= response.json()["status"];
} else {
    console.log('request failed', response);
}
```

*Explanation*

`fetch(URL)` returns `Promise<Response>` and the Response implements the [`Body`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#bodyjson) interface which means that `response.json()` returns another promise  you should "await" on.

Further, you'll be able to fetch `response.json()` only if the response returned `ok` which means that this code should be executed inside the wrapping `if (response.ok) { ...`.

For more, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#fetchurl-options

Comment: I get an error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.json is not a function
    at get_status (index.js:42)"

Comment: try to get it as text first: `const json = await response.text();` and see what it returns. By the way, only if `response.ok` is truthy - you should go ahead and call `response.json()` IIRC

Comment: const json = await response.text;
I get None. 
With brackets: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.text is not a function
    at get_status (index.js:42)

Comment: @Natalia get the update code from the answer please

Comment: Oh, I get the data! But where is this big difference between variants?

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me a lot of time!